# How to choose a Bluetooth address

Tags: bluetooth

I am working on a project involving Bluetooth and am supposed to start uploading software to the units. When I am going to burn the OTP I have to state the Bluetooth address. I know that there are public and random addresses, but I can't figure out how to choose the right one. I am not interested in getting a public address from IEEE and the address just need to be static.

Is the only requirements I have to fulfill then to have the two most significant bits set to 1 and not have only ones or zeros as the remaining 46 bits?

If so, what would happen if I upload the same address to multiple devices? Would that create problems or could I in principle just have 0xC000000000000001 as the address for all of my units?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would not duplicate the addresses as this causes a problem differentiating between two devices that are discovered with the same address. Because Bluetooth devices have a limited range it doesn't matter if the same address is used twice if they are not in the same location. I assume that this is why Random Static Addresses don't have to guarantee no address clashes.

For your situation it would make sense to randomly generate the Bluetooth address. A variation on the answers in the following question: [MAC address generator in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8484877/7721752) depending what language you have available.

There is a good reference on Bluetooth Addresses at:

https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-address-privacy-ble/

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I am still a little confused about some things. If the Random Static Address is generated randomly, there will be some chance of creating an address that is already registered at IEEE. And on that note, do you know what the pros of paying for a IEEE unique address when you could just create one randomly?